# Why does incrementing a pointer work, but treating it as an array fail? Part 2

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I think I figured out what the problem is: C is stinky. It treats locally declared pointers one way and pointers passed as parameters another. This is in response to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765173/why-does-incrementing-a-pointer-work-but-treating-it-as-an-array-fail) I posted a couple of days ago. I tried to post it there, but the program wouldn't fit.

```
// Test arrays and pointers

#include <stdio.h>
//  #include <string.h>

#define EOL "\n"

typedef struct
{
    int useless1;
    int useless2;
}   type1;

void function1(char* s)
{
    printf("Pointer to string.  ");
    while (*s)
        putchar(*s++);

    printf(EOL);
}

void function2(char* s)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Index into string.  ");
    while (s[i])
        putchar(s[i++]);

    printf(EOL);
}

void functionX1(type1* p, int count)
{
    printf("Pointer to struct." EOL);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, p->useless1);
        printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, p->useless2);
        p++;
    }
    printf(EOL);
}

void functionX2(type1* p, int count)
{
    printf("Index into array of structures." EOL);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, p[i].useless1);
        printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, p[i].useless2);
    }
    printf(EOL);
}

void getptr1(char* s, char** ss)
{
    *ss = s;
}

void getptr2(type1* ptr, type1** pptr)
{
    *pptr = ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
// Work with strings of characters

    char* s;

    function1( argv[0]);
    function2( argv[0]);
    function1(*argv   );
    function2(*argv   );

    getptr1(argv[0], &s);
    function1(        s);
    function2(        s);

    printf("main Pointer to string.  ");
    while (*s)
        putchar(*s++);
    printf(EOL);

    int i=0;
    printf("main Index into string.  ");
    while (s[i])
        putchar(s[i++]);
    printf(EOL);

// Work with array of structures
    #define count   3

    type1   a[count];

    int x1 = 123;
    int x2 = 789000;
    int kx = 111;

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        a[i].useless1 = x1;
        a[i].useless2 = x2;
        x1 +=  kx;
        x2 += (kx * 1000);
    }

//    functions1(&a   , count);     Fail
//    functions2(&a   , count);     Fail
    functionX1(&a[0], count);
    functionX2(&a[0], count);
    functionX1( a   , count);
    functionX2( a   , count);

    type1*  b;

    getptr2(a, &b);
    functionX1( b   , count);
    functionX2( b   , count);

    printf("main Pointer to struct." EOL);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, b->useless1);
        printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, b->useless2);
        b++;
    }
    printf(EOL);

    printf("main Index into array of structures." EOL);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, b[i].useless1);
        printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, b[i].useless2);
    }
    printf(EOL);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Add link to your earlier question. That would be more helpful to understand.

Comment: C is stinky? you should add it to the tag description

Comment: Who is it you are asking? The people who are really good at working with C? You know, those who probably like C. And you invite those people to answer, by saying "C is stinky". Interesting.

Comment: You post a wall of code and say something doesn't work. _What_ doesn't work? What's the output and the expected output? And please post a [mcve]

Comment: Add stinky tag to make it more appropriate

Comment: _It treats locally declared pointers one way and pointers passed as parameters another_: not sure what you mean here, could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but this code probably doesn't do what you want:

```
printf("main Pointer to struct." EOL);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, b->useless1);
    printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, b->useless2);
    b++;
}
printf(EOL);

printf("main Index into array of structures." EOL);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, b[i].useless1);
    printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, b[i].useless2);
}
printf(EOL);
```

The first loop changes the value of `b`, so the second loop doesn't start where you think it does.

Consider something like this:

```
type1* bOrig = b; // store the original value
printf("main Pointer to struct." EOL);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, b->useless1);
    printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, b->useless2);
    b++;
}
printf(EOL);
b = bOrig; // restore the original value

printf("main Index into array of structures." EOL);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("index: %d  useless1: %d" EOL, i, b[i].useless1);
    printf("index: %d  useless2: %d" EOL, i, b[i].useless2);
}
printf(EOL);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I thought the link to the original question would help, but it doesn't explain this piece of code.

Comment: This program demonstrates that in some cases you can treat a pointer as a pointer OR as an array, but in some cases you cannot. Run the program and all the results are the same EXCEPT for two instances: the last string example ('main Index into string. ') and the last structure example ("main Index into array of structures."). These two instances fail to deliver the data. So my question is why do these two examples fail? The only difference I can see is that the code for the two failures is in the main body where the pointers are declared instead of being contained in a function.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I thought this program demonstrated my original problem, but it only fails because I made an error, which smarx pointed out. So back to the drawing board.